# Event Viewer Errors: Address <IP> being plumbed for adapter <number> already exists

Tags: networking, dhcp, network-adapter, event-log

I'm seeing these errors repeating ~every 5 minutes in my Administrative Events:

> Address 192.168.0.195 being plumbed for adapter 18 already exists

and

> An error has occurred in initializing the interface 18. Error Code is 0x1392

Doing a `route print` shows that adapter 18 (shown with the green box in the screenshot below) is the hardware NIC on my MOBO, named "Intel® l211 (etc.)" a.k.a. "LAN", which is required for my computer to have internet access.

I also have a software NIC that is setup when enabling Hyper-V, a Bridge I believe, named "vEthernet Hyper-V [External]", shown in the orange box, which is also required for the computer to have internet access.

[image]

I have both of those set to automatically get their IP4 DNS settings via their properties.

My thought is that somehow the router is getting these 2 adapters "confused" and wanting to set them both to the same IP, thus giving the hardware NIC an error?

I have read here:

https://richardcarterorg.wordpress.com/2011/05/10/event-id-50034-50068/

that disabling one should "fix" the issue, but as mentioned, my machine requires both in order to have network/internet access; disabling wither one of them disconnects me from the net. I have also tired temporarily disable/re-enabling each one to see if that sorted things out, but it did not.

Anyone have any idea how to solved this error?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue on my Hyper-V hypervisor and believe I figured out what causes it...

The MAC address of my primary network card, the one referenced in the event log, matches the MAC address of my Hyper-V Virtual Switch. I confirmed this using the 'ipconfig /all' command in command prompt.

My primary network card has a statically assigned address, but I also added a DHCP reservation for that MAC address on the DHCP server, in case the static setting ever got cleared out for some reason.

So DHCP is seeing the MAC address of my Hyper-V Virtual Switch, which matches my primary network card, and is trying to assign the Hyper-V Virtual Switch the same IP that I have set statically on my primary network card.

Long story short, I am guessing you have a DHCP reservation set up for the MAC address of your 'LAN' network adapter, and your Hyper-V Virtual Switch 'vEthernet (Hyper-V [External])', is trying to pick up the same IP as your LAN network adapter.